# Android - Format Timestamp in ListView with Cursor Adapter

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp, android-listview

I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate an Android ListView, and was wondering how I should go about getting all of the timestamps I get from a database, each in "DATE_DATE" into human readable dates, maybe using SimpleDateFormat?

```
Cursor programDateCursor = mDbAdapter.loadProgramDates();

startManagingCursor(programDateCursor);

String[] from = new String[]{ "DATE_DATE" };

int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.text1 };

SimpleCursorAdapter programDates = 
             new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.program_date,
                                      programDateCursor, from, to);

setListAdapter(programDates);
```

I've not done much work with Java, so is there a better way / any way to do this? Other than storing the preformatted dates in the database before hand, that is?

Comment: What format are your timestamps in? Milliseconds?

Comment: @Glendon, Unix timestamps, made with PHP's time() / strtotime() functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're going to have to create a custom CursorAdapter to be able to format your timestamps.

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, false);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
         return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.program_date, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        long time = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("DATE_DATE")) * 1000L;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(time);

        String format = "M/dd h:mm a";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        String dateString = sdf.format(cal.getTime());

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(dateString);
    }
}
```

The list to change the `String format` to your liking is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You'd then use this adapter with

```
Cursor programDateCursor = mDbAdapter.loadProgramDates();
startManagingCursor(programDateCursor);

setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, programDateCursor));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! Would you happen to have a good resource on learning to work with Cursors / Adapters in Android? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. I basically just copied this from my app and deleted some things.  I haven't found a very comprehensive resource on adapters, but I learn most stuff here on Stack Overflow.  `newView()` (inflates your layout) and `bindView()` (receives your layout and adds information) are the two main methods you need to override.  `getView()` might be one you could research as well.  Other than that, you can do whatever you want to your cursor data before displaying it in the `ListView`.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but how do I tell this to populate a specific ListView in a specific file.xml? That is, I need to have some stuff in the top 33% of the screen, then have this fill up the ListView that takes up the bottom 2/3s. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, removing `android:id="@android:id/empty"` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Store Unix epoch dates as `INTEGER` type in SQLite database. Then in Java, initialize them with `new Date(value)` (or `value*1000`, I'm not sure) and use `SimpleDateFormat` to format dates in list adapter.

I think that's the most convenient way for the limited information you've provided.

Comment: I know how to do that part, I meant more how do I change each one of the DATE_DATEs in the programDateCursor into the proper text before I pass them off to the new SimpleCursorAdapter? Should I just iterate over the cursor and format them each individually? If so, how? Or can I just send a filter function into SimpleCursorAdapter somehow? Or should I not be using a SimpleCursorAdapter at all?

Comment: I think you can implement your own cursor (or list) adapter. That will be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easiest to do the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat oldTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat newTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");

String stringTime;

try {

        String reformattedStr = newTime.format(oldTime.parse(stringTime));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```