# Problem converting time from database to ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, listview

I need to convert a Time field(milliseconds) from a databse into "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm" and list that result in a listview in ascending order and I'm having troubled getting the DateTime to show up on my listview.
Here's the code i'm using:

DB:

```
public Cursor getUserDateTimeLocations(long rowId) throws SQLException
        {
        Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_LOCATION, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE, KEY_DATETIME,KEY_USERID,KEY_OBS}, KEY_USERID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

Listview right now I can show the DateTime field but I need to convert the field for every row and then show it and this I don't know how to do it:

```
private void dateTime() {
    cursor = db.getUserDateTimeLocations(mLocationRowId);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm");
    mTime= cursor.getLong(3);
    Date resultdate = new Date(mTime);
    String mDateTime = sdf.format(resultdate);
    //Toast.makeText(this, mDateTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_DATETIME};<--How to do it here?
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.label};

    SimpleCursorAdapter locations = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.user_row, cursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(locations);

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417550/android-format-timestamp-in-listview-with-cursor-adapter/6419338#6419338

Comment: Thanks. It worked! Now any idea on how to get the datetime in ascending order in my query? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only special part of your SimpleCursorAdapter the following will help. Add this  code in front of your setListAdapter call:

```
locations.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(final View view, final Cursor cursor, final int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) view;

                long millis = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
                textView.setText(yourFormattingOfMillisToDateHere);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is override setViewText in CursorAdapter.
Few lines of my code resolving identical problem:

```
private class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);

    }

    private Date d = new Date();

    @Override
    public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.TrackTime) {
            d.setTime(Long.parseLong(text));
            text = d.toLocaleString();
        }
        super.setViewText(v, text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to roll your own adapter. SimpleCursorAdapter is just that - a simple way to bind fields from a DB to a textview of some sort. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026071253/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/08/custom-view-in-your-listactivity-and.html) link for a good walkthrough.