# Formatting cursoritems before populating the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

Im selecting titles and startdates from events of my calendar and want to show them in a list.
But currently the startdate is in milliseconds and therefore unreadable for the user.
 Is there a clever way to format my eventstartdate, before populating the listview.

```
cur = cr.query(uri, new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,...                        
final String[] arrayColumns = new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART};
int[] arrayViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.textTitle, R.id.textDate};

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_item, cur, arrayColumns, arrayViewIDs, 0);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417550/android-format-timestamp-in-listview-with-cursor-adapter

Comment: made it work, thank you!